# Figuring the time complexity of this code

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

I was trying to solve [this](https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/6-sorting/distinct/) question, and below is my code.

```
import java.util.*;

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// System.out.println("this is a debug message");

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
    Set <Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
            set.add(A[i]);
        }
        return set.size();
        // write your code in Java SE 8
    }
}
```

My question is what is the time complexity of this code. I assumed it to be O(n). n being the number of elements but my test results says it has detected time complexity of O(n*log n). Could you please tell me the correct answer with a brief explanation?

Comment: For one you know `A.length` but the set has to grow adaptively, I'd guess by doubling it's capacity (or a similar exponential) copying the elements (maybe even rehashing them) leading to some `n * log n` operations. Try initialising the set correctly by using [`HashSet(int, float)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet(int,%20float)) and see if that still produces the same behaviour. Be conservative about the initial capacity, choose a capacity larger than `A.length`.

Answer (score 0):

The *expected*, *amortized* cost of an insertion into a `HashMap` in Java is O(1). This means that if you do a series of n insertions into a `HashMap`, then *on average* the runtime will be O(n) provided that you have a good hash function. The "on average" part refers to the fact that there is some inherent randomness about how objects get distributed, which means that it's possible it might take longer than that. The "best" way to characterize the runtime would be "expected O(n)," but with an understanding that if you get really, really unlucky it could be longer than that.